# What does enable_testing() do in cmake?

Tags: unit-testing, cmake

I see that to add my google tests(for my cpp project), I need to make a call to enable_testing() in the root source directory. Can someone explain what this really does? Also why would cmake not make this default?

This is all I could get from the documentation.

> Enables testing for this directory and below. See also the add_test()
>   command. Note that ctest expects to find a test file in the build
>   directory root. Therefore, this command should be in the source
>   directory root.

Comment: The official document is so pool!

Answer (score 34):

When you call [`add_test(...)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html), CMake will not generate the tests unless [`enable_testing()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_testing.html) has been called. Note that you usually don't need to call this directly. Just [`include(CTest)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CTest.html) and it will invoke it for you.

My CMake setup often looks like this:

```cmake
include(CTest) # note: this adds a BUILD_TESTING which defaults to ON

# ...

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  add_subdirectory(tests)
endif()
```

In the **tests** directory:

```cmake
# setup test dependencies
# googletest has some code they explain on how to set it up; put that here

add_executable(MyUnitTests
    # ...
)

target_link_libraries(MyUnitTests gtest_main)

add_test(MyUnitTestName MyUnitTests)
```

Comment: Since `include(CTest)` internally invokes `enable_testing()`, does it mean that it's no meaning to manually invoke `enable_testing()`?

Answer (score 18):

It [sets a definition](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/c6c8c24908e108b7b3c5c76e29197323ac3a4287/Source/cmEnableTestingCommand.cxx) in the generator, `CMAKE_TESTING_ENABLED`, which, if *not* defined, allows cmake to skip a lot of additional processing related to the registration of unit-tests with ctest. [(example)](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/d4b97e8d721e5a5374a400bcdd5df1eb4e1cf7d2/Source/cmLocalGenerator.cxx#L241:L322)

The major benefit of this is that it allows you to selectively enable/disable the generation of tests in your build files, when calling cmake.

As an example, you could put the following snippet in your root `CMakeLists.txt file`:

It creates an option to enable tests, which are off by default.

```
option(ENABLE_TESTS "Enable tests" OFF)
if (${ENABLE_TESTS})
    enable_testing()
endif()
```

You only need to do this once, in your root `CMakeLists.txt`, and in the rest of your cmake files you can happily call `add_test()` etc, without having to worry about checking `if (${ENABLE_TESTS})` every time